# jQuery not working in Velocity 1.5

Tags: jquery, velocity

I am trying to achieve the following my code using jquery  in velocity template but jQuery is not at all responding. I am using velocity 1.5

Please provide a solution.

```
<script src="/CostTrackerReporting/WebContent/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.test").replaceWith("<h1>TEST</h1>");
});
 </script>  



<div id="test">
    <p>TETSIGN</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you use jquery in no conflict mode. This means you can not use $ any more instead you have to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("div.test").replaceWith("<h1>TEST</h1>");
});
```

Why is that? Because jQuery will not use the dollar sign in case any other library is using it.

Comment: "not working" is not very informative. What happens?

Comment: @Shubhra can you have a look at the console (e.g. via right click->inspect->console) and tell if there is an error message?

Comment: I am getting the following when I check console ....                                            "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:9081/CostTrackerReporting/WebContent/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
jquery-....min.js
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Shubhra: You get a 404 error referencing the JS-file, That means the link to the file in your script-tag is not correct. It could be a filename-error or some issue with your localhost. To make sure that is the problem try replacing your script-tag with this: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

Now you are getting jQuery from the web. If it works now you need to fix the link to your .js-file.

Comment: @user2672106 : using   <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"> , it is working ... May be I am missing the path some . Thank You